In a C# Windows Form how should I unsubscribe from events in the code behind given that I dont want to modify code in the designer?
A C# Windows form has the generated dispose method code in it's designer File
partial class DetailRibbonForm2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
   // etc

I want to add some code to the code behind file that will unsubscribe from events at dispose time.
How do I do this?
If I try to override Dispose in the Code Behind I get

error CS0111: Type 'DetailRibbonForm2' already defines a member called
'Dispose' with the same parameter types


There are shutdown events that are raised when a Form/Application is closed. The FormClosed event exists for such tasks. See the remarks. Override the OnFormClosed method for that.

"that will unsubscribe from events" - if all you're doing is detaching the event handler from e.g. savebutton.Click, don't worry about it

@dr.null Which do you prefer and why?

Well, it's a partial class so moving the method from one file to another is perfectly legitimate. However, following the design is a good practice. Keep the designer-generated code as is since you have a way in your implementation to do what you need to do.

Also, forgot to mention, if you subscribe to handlers that use the Form's Handle property, unless you're 100% sure that you want change anything at runtime that causes handle recreation (i.e. changing some Form's properties requires calling RecreateHandle method in the base class...), then you should override the OnHandleCreated method to subscribe, and OnHandleDestroyed method to unsubscribe. As you can see, it depends.

Did you try just putting your custom dispose logic in that existing method? Note that it is "not" within the #region Windows Form Designer generated code block and therefore shouldn't get overwritten. It's just another member method of DetailRibbonForm2. In fact, you can move it from DetailRibbonForm2.Designer.cs to DetailRibbonForm2.cs without penalty if you prefer.

I generally move the Dispose function out of the designer file and into the main form file when I customise it; it makes it less hidden.

You may notice that the Dispose() is placed outside the "Windows Form Designer generated code, do not edit" region. So, you can  safely modify it.
Another point is that the .designer.cs files are not something that I would expect to be edited manually, so I personally prefer just to move the generated Dispose() implementation from the form.designer.cs to the form.cs and then extend that implementation as needed. Newer has any form designer related issues because of this.
